# Render font in in IE 8 and below (working in all other browsers)

Tags: css, internet-explorer, fonts, font-face, webfonts

I can't make IE 8 and below (need preferably upto IE 6) render a font I have on my server.

The code I'm using is the following:

```
@font-face { 
    font-family:omnes; 
    src:url('fonts/Omnes-Regular.eot') format('eot'), 
        url('fonts/Omnes-Regular.otf') format('otf'),
        url('fonts/Omnes-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

This seems to work for all other browsers, how can I approach this?

You can see a live demo here:

http://trufavarela.com/uruware/

Comment: Guide here: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'omnes';
    src: url('fonts/Omnes-Regular.eot');
    src: url('fonts/Omnes-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/Omnes-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

You probably do not need otf file format. This code is likely to work, because when IE tries getting anything other, than the eot format, the ? simply makes it think the rest of the string is a parameter, as in a php file.

Also, you should probably include woff and svg formats of the font as well. And use [Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/), does all the job for you.

Comment: It seems to work for IE, thanks but somehow, now they are looking weird in chrome! http://trufavarela.com/uruware/2012/11/03/objetivo-cumplido/ any idea why?

Comment: I think that is simply the difference between the rendering engines, I don't see them to be that different.

Comment: Font squirrel did it for me, great resource! Thanks!